# How to connect to integrated Visual Studio 2012 SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm just trying to connect to the SQL Server that is integrated in Visual Studio 2012 so I can, after that, create a database programatically.

I just have installed Visual Studio 2012 Professional with default options. When I open Server Explorer I can see an active server named as my computer. The simplest connection string I have tried is:

```
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master");
myConn.Open()
```

I get this error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I have tried with many other server names. Providing my computer's name is "MyLaptop", I have tried:

- `Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS`
- `Server=MyLaptop`
- `Server=MyLaptop\\SQLEXPRESS`
- `Server=(LocalDB)\\v11.0`

Could you please help me?

Comment: Solved. Problem was that the integrated SQL Server is the SQL Server Compact Edition, wich uses another set of classes. Instead is SQlConnection it uses SQLCeConnection. As far I can see it does not allow to connect only to the server. You must connect to an existing database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Problem was that the integrated SQL Server is the SQL Server Compact Edition, wich uses another set of classes. Instead is SQlConnection it uses SQLCeConnection. As far I can see it does not allow to connect only to the server. You must connect to an existing database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master");
myConn.Open()
```